# How to find a catenary given 3 points

Tags: calculus, geometry

The points are (0,0), (1.11,3.771), (2.4,-.279). The middle point is the turning point. I have researched everywhere and tried to just figure it out on my own but am having real trouble.

Comment: See section 4 here: http://www.stem2.org/je/catenary.pdf

Comment: @RobertZ I did see that but I don't get it

Comment: From (0, 0) to (2.4, -0.279) the function is decreasing. If there is a turning point then its y coordinate must be between 0 and -0.279, as its x (i.e 1.11) is between 0 and 2.4. There must be something wrong in statement of problem.

Comment: @Sirius the function is not decreasing.  The catenary opens downwards.

Comment: then the mid point is not called turning point. it is called maximum point.